# Black screen after setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nslayoutconstraint

I have a Scrollview with a a label. To center the label in the top center, I apply two constraints to it:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-30-[questionLabel]"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:0
                                                               views:viewsDictionary]];
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.questionLabel
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:self
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:.0]];
```

Without setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints for questionLabel to NO, I will run into an exception thrown by Core Layout. It warns me that it could not satisfy the following constraint:

```
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8e3baf0 V:|-(30)-[UILabel:0xa184ca0]   (Names: '|':WLQuestionnaireSingleQuestionView:0xa184050 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8e3efa0 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0xa184ca0.midY == + 15>"
```

)

In there I see that Core Layout tried to satisfy a constraint which has been automatically generated to be backwards compatible with autoresizing mask. In my understanding, the fix for this should be to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO, but unfortunately that results in a completely black screen, no debug messages.

I implemented the view programmatically, no nibs.

Comment: i'm fighting the same type of behaviour. have you found a workaround?

Comment: I'm sorry, it had been too long ago and I don't have access to the source anymore. I believe there was a workaround as a very specific solution for my problem (probably avoiding this issue in the first place), but I cannot say I have the solution to this specific problem right now.

Comment: Do you have a sample project? Did you try changing the label background color to see where it is? How is your screen black? What's the background color of the root view?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see this question is quite old already. However I want to give an answer to this as it may still be interesting for others. As you are using an `UIScrollView` with AutoLayout, the content size is determined by the constraints. As you don't have a constraint from your view to the bottom, the height cannot be set correctly. Same thing for the width as you didn't specify any width for your view. You just told the AutoLayout that it should be located in the center of the view. Your problem could be solved using the following code (view width = 40):

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(30)-[questionLabel]|"
                                                         options:0
                                                         metrics:0
                                                           views:viewsDictionary]];
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.questionLabel
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:self
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:.0]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[questionLabel(40)]", options: 0, metrics: 0, views: viewsDictionary]];
```